# Normal distribution with shortened units

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, variance, standard-deviation

I was solving an exam problem:

Website's number of clicks per month is a random variable with normal distribution, where the mean is 12 and the variance is 2 (both in millions). Calculate the probability that 15 000 000 clicks per month occur.

Here is the catch: there is a difference between a normal distribution with the mean of 12 000 000 and variance of 2 000 000, and a normal distribution with the mean of 12 and the variance of 2.

If I went along with units in millions, so a normal distribution with the mean of 12 and the variance of 2, this would be my result using transformed variables:
$$U = \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$$
where $\mu=12$ and $\sigma = \sqrt{2}$

$$1-\Phi(\frac{15-12}{\sqrt{2}})=0.016947$$

If I went along with bare numbers, this would be my result:

$$U = \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$$
where $\mu=12 000 000$ and $\sigma = \sqrt{2000000}$

$$1-\Phi(\frac{15000000-12000000}{\sqrt{2000000}})=0.00000000001$$

The first result was correct, and I got it right, but nonetheless I think that the problem was stated confusingly and ambiguously. I know why the difference happens, all I'm asking is: What should my intuition be in cases like this? I wrote the problem verbatim, they really did mix units in millions and bare units. What is your take on this?

Comment: If you were measuring something in say megawatts, and it had a mean of 12 and variance of 2 then the mean would be measured in megawatts (so 12 megawatts or 12 million watts) and the variance in megawatts squared (so 2 megawatts squared or 2 million million watts squared).  You are right to identify an ambiguity of saying the variance is 2 when the unit appears to be millions.

Comment: @Henry thank you for confirming what I thought. It wouldn't be ambiguous if the unit of variance was specified in millions squared.

Comment: @Henry sorry for double posting, but if it was specified to be 2 million squared, would that make it 2 million million, or 4 million million (do we square the unit only or the number as well?)

Comment: You are told the variance is $2$ somethings, so it is not $4$